# createDataPartition in R

Tags: r, random-forest

With caret package, when creating data partition, how do we do the partition? For e.g. I have seen 75% training and 25% test, 50% training and 50% test, 80% training and 20% test…which one is more suitable?

Comment: It is hard to give a straightforward answer since the split will depend on many factor including the size of your dataset and the application. A standard training/testing split is 80/20% where 1/5 of the data is kept for testing. I suggest you read more on this topic. For example: https://machinelearningmastery.com/train-test-split-for-evaluating-machine-learning-algorithms/

Comment: This is not a specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow. If you want advice about modeling your data, you should ask for help at [stats.se] or [datascience.se].